# Outdated Servers Unable to Access World

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to get onto my brother's world on Minecraft PE. It is saying
`Outdated server 0.14.0`. We both have iPad 2s with the latest software updates and can access a world on my other brother's iPad Air. Very frustrating. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

If only one of you has the latest update(0.14.1), it is a version error. Check the App Store to confirm you have the latest version.

Your brother's iPad air and your iPad 2 both have 0.14.1, because the message says **out**dated server with your brother's iPad 2.

So, to fix this, simply update Minecraft.

If that doesn't work, go here:https://blogs.windows.com/devices/2015/09/18/how-to-play-multiplayer-minecraft-pocket-edition/.

Answer (score 0):

Minecraft PE 0.14's protocol and Minecraft PE 0.14.1's protocol are not compatible with each other, so you are not able to join 0.14 servers with 0.14.1 and vice versa. And app downgrades are not possible on iOS. The only solution is to wait until the server updates its software to 0.14.1.